# Counterexample for statements regarding to Raabe and convergence

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

1. Is there seq $\{a_n\}$ which absolutely converges and satisfies following condition:

For any given $L>1$, there exists $n_{L}\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1-1/n \geq |a_{n+1}/a_{n}| \geq 1-L/n$ for $n\geq n_{L}$.

2. Is is possible :$c_n>0, b_n \neq 0$, $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n/c_n \neq 1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (b_n-c_n)$ converges but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n$ diverges.
   (Here, $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n/c_n$ converges)

Answer (score 1):

1. Let $a_n=\dfrac{1}{n(\log n)^2}$. Then $\sum a_n<\infty$ and
   $$
   1-\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n\log n}+O\Bigl(\frac{1}{n^2}\Bigr).
   $$

2.
$$
b_n=\frac{2+(-1)^n}{n},\quad c_n=\frac{2}{n}.
$$
In this example $b_n/c_n$ does not converge.

2'. Let $d_n=b_n-c_n$. The we want to find $c_n>0$ and $d_n$ such that $\sum c_n=+\infty$, $c_n+d_n\ne0$, $\sum d_n$ converges and $\lim_{n\to\infty}d_n/c_n=\ell$ exists and $\ell\ne0$. If $\ell>0$ then $d_n>0$ for all $n$ large enough, and by the comparison test $\sum c_n$ and $\sum d_n$ have the same character. Similarly if $\ell<0$. Thus there is no such counterexample. This works also if $\ell=\pm\infty$.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I omitted some condition in question 2. ration of b_n and c_n must converge.

Comment: Then there is no such example. See the edited answer.

Comment: Very thank you! But Big O notation is quite unfamiliar... So, would you tell me in detail about the equality in second line?.. (I mean, can we prove above result(number 1) without using Big O notation)

Comment: $O(1/n^2)$ means $\le C/n^2$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: oh, I mean the terms 1/n and 2/(n log n) where come from? Through power series expansion?

Comment: Yes. For instance, $\log(n+1)=\log n+\log(1+1/n)=\log n+1/n+O(1/n^2)$.